# Having some problem in displaying the output of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my coding and why it is not displaying the output and keeps showing me the prompt only? there is something wrong in my if statements and I can't figure out what it is I tried many things but it still now working any suggestions? it supposes to be the same as the picture [the final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW1v9.png) and the prompt must show only when I write zero days like the picture [prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob7We.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<style>

body{
background-color:orange;
margin:20px;
}


</style>


<title> Assignment2</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
<p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>


<form>
<label><b> GUEST:</b> </label> 

 <input type="text" id="fname" size="20" > 
 <input type="text" id="lname" size="20" > 
 
 <br>
 <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
 <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>
 
 <br><br>
 
 <label ><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
 <input type="date" id="date">
 
 <br><br>
 
 <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>
 
 <select id="room">
    <option value=30>King $30</option>
    <option value=20>Double $20</option>
    <option value=10>Single $10</option>
  </select>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
  <input type="text" size="12" id="days">

<br><br> 

<label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>
  
<br>


<button  type="reset"  STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;" > CLEAR </button>
<button  type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;" > BOOK </button>
</form>

<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result">  </p>



<script>

var Fname= document.getElementById("fname").value;
var Lname= document.getElementById("lname").value;
var date= document.getElementById("date").value;
var days= document.getElementById("days").value;
var request= document.getElementById("request").value;
var total="";

function myFunction(){
          
var n = Number(document.getElementById("days").value);
var val= Number( document.getElementById("room").value);
var total="";


        if (n<=0){

                n=prompt(" minimum reservation period is 1 day try again");
                }
             
            
         else if (val == "King $30") {

         total = n * 30; 
         } 
         else if (val == "Double $20")  {

         total = n * 20;
         }  
         else if (val == "Single $10") {
         total = n * 10;
         } else {
         }

  
        
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us."+
"<br>"+" Expected Arrival Date: " + date +
"<br>" + " Booked: " + val + " for " + n + "days " +
"<br>" +"Amount:=$ " + total +
"<br>" + " Any Special Request: " + request ;


};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: You need to put `var n = Number(document.getElementById("days").value);` (with fixed typo), along with any other value that might change after the page loads, *inside* myFunction

Answer (score 1):

Do not use form with no action

Check this out:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var Fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var Lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
  var request = document.getElementById("request").value;
  var val = Number(document.getElementById("room").value);
  var n = Number(document.getElementById("days").value);
  var total = "";


  if (n < 3) {
    console.log(n);
    n = alert("Minimum reservation period is 2 daye try again");
  } else if (val == "King $30") {

    total = n * 30;
  } else if (val == "Double 20") {

    total = n * 20;

  } else if (val == "Single 10") {

    total = n * 10;
  } else {

  }


  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + ' ' + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us.";
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = " Expected Arrival Date: " + date;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = " Booked: " + val + " for " + days + "days ";
  document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = " Amount:=$ " + total;
  document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = " Any Special Request: " + request;

  window.location.hash = '#result';

};
```

```html
<h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
<p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>

<label><b> GUEST:</b> </label>

<input type="text" id="fname" size="20">
<input type="text" id="lname" size="20">

<br>
<label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
<label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>

<br><br>

<label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
<input type="date" id="date">

<br><br>

<label><b>Room Type:</b></label>
<input list="room">
<datalist id="room">
    <option value="King $30">
    <option value="Double $20">
    <option value="Single $10">
  </datalist>

<br><br>

<label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
<input type="number" id="days">

<br><br>

<label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>

<br>


<button type="reset" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> CLEAR </button>
<button type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> BOOK </button>


<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result1"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result2"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result3"> </p>
<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result4"> </p>
```

Comment: You should not use variables outside of function

Comment: can you check my new code i changed the format and I tried your way and it is not working

Comment: *Do not use form with no action* what relevance is this?   There is no `form` and it would make no difference to the code.

Comment: dont declare variables outside of function and there is ")" missing on var n line

Comment: your code wont work if you declare variables outside of function

Comment: copy and test new answer

Comment: Well, it's more about *setting* the variables, not *declaring* them.

Comment: its bad way to decalre or set block variables outside of function

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: orange;
      margin: 20px;
    }
  </style>


  <title> Assignment2</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
  <p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>


  <label><b> GUEST:</b> </label>

  <input type="text" id="fname" size="20">
  <input type="text" id="lname" size="20">

  <br>
  <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
  <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
  <input type="date" id="date">

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>

  <select id="room">
    <option value=30>King $30</option>
    <option value=20>Double $20</option>
    <option value=10>Single $10</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
  <input type="text" size="12" id="days">

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>

  <br>


  <button type="reset" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> CLEAR </button>
  <button type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> BOOK </button>


  <p style="background-color:blue;" id="result"> </p>



  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var n = Number(document.getElementById("days").value);
      var val = Number(document.getElementById("room").value);

      var Fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var Lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
      var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
      var request = document.getElementById("request").value;
      var total = "";

      if (n <= 0) {

        n = prompt(" minimum reservation period is 1 day try again");
      } else if (val == "King $30") {

        total = n * 30;
      } else if (val == "Double $20") {

        total = n * 20;
      } else if (val == "Single $10") {
        total = n * 10;
      } else {}



      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us." +
        "<br>" + " Expected Arrival Date: " + date +
        "<br>" + " Booked: " + val + " for " + n + "days " +
        "<br>" + "Amount:=$ " + total +
        "<br>" + " Any Special Request: " + request;
        window.location.hash = '#result';

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
var Lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
var request = document.getElementById("request").value;
var total = "";

function myFunction() {

  var val = Number(document.getElementById("room").value);
  var n = Number(document.getElementById("days").value);
  if (n <= 0) {
    console.log(n);
    prompt(" minimum reservation period is 1 day try again");
  } else if (val == "King $30") {

    total = n * 30;
  } else if (val == "Double $20") {

    total = n * 20;
  } else if (val == "Single $10") {
    total = n * 10;
  } else {}

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = " Dear " + Fname + Lname + " , thank you for booking with us." +
    "<br>" + " Expected Arrival Date: " + date +
    "<br>" + " Booked: " + val + " for " + n + "days " +
    "<br>" + "Amount:=$ " + total +
    "<br>" + " Any Special Request: " + request;


};
```

```html
<h3> Hotel Registration Form </h3>
<p style="color:green">BOOK YOUR STAY WITH US...!</p>


<form>
  <label><b> GUEST:</b> </label>

  <input type="text" id="fname" size="20">
  <input type="text" id="lname" size="20">

  <br>
  <label style="margin-left:65px"> First Name </label>
  <label style="margin-left:105px"> Last Name </label>

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Arrival Date:</b></label>
  <input type="date" id="date">

  <br><br>

  <label><b>Room Type:</b></label>

  <select id="room">
    <option value=30>King $30</option>
    <option value=20>Double $20</option>
    <option value=10>Single $10</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Number of Days:</b></label>
  <input type="number" id="days"><span id="demo"></span>

  <br><br>

  <label><b> Any Special Request:</b></label>
  <br>
  <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="request"></textarea>

  <br>


  <button type="reset" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> CLEAR </button>
  <button type="submit" onClick="myFunction()" STYLE="background-color:red;border:offset;"> BOOK </button>
</form>

<p style="background-color:blue;" id="result"> </p>
```

Try this it will work:
your function was unable to access the variables